# I want to refresh a div content with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to refresh a div with ajax but when i select items from mysql it does not refresh the page. here is my code

INDEX.PHP page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#divToRefresh').load('cart.php');
        }, 3000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds.
    });
</script>
<div id="divToRefresh"></div>
```

Here is the CART.PHP page

```
<?php 
    include "admin/konet.php"; 
    $itemsTotal = mysql_query("select sum(quantity) as `quantity` from `products_added` where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["REMOTE_ADDR"])."'"); 
    $get_itemsTotal = mysql_fetch_array($itemsTotal);
    $items = ($get_itemsTotal["quantity"]); //Get total of all product
    echo '<font id="cat">'.$items.'</font>';
?>
```

Comment: First glance cart.php does not output anything.

Comment: A `<font>` tag? Wow, that's old school..

Comment: [Your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/qhue4/). You need to check whether anything is really being passed from your PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP code currently shown in your question does not output anything, so your AJAX request will just receive an empty response. There is a commented `echo` statement, have you tried adding it again?

I would go about this as follows: Open `cart.php` directly in the browser. Work on it until you achieve the desired output. Only then add the AJAX call. You can also use Firebug or similar tools to verify the AJAX output. In the end, AJAX is nothing more than an ordinary HTTP request to your server, only that it's initiated by client-side JS.

You can also use something like `print_r($get_itemsTotal)` to debug the DB interaction.

**Unrelated, but important:** You should consider switching to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), as the `mysql_*` API is deprecated. Prefer prepared statements to manual escaping of query parameters.